# Rails 5 Integration Test is only using fixtures values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write tests in rails 5. I modified a little the generated scaffold test. But it appears to get from somewhere the fixtures and only run the test using this source.

The 'create' method on controller accepts one user with email and a list of pages with url.

My test class:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "test" do
    assert_difference('User.count', 1) do
      post users_url, params: { user: { email: 'a@a' }, pages:[{url:'a'},{url:'b'},{url:'c'}] }, as: :json
    end

    assert_response 201
  end
end

-------------------- fixtures --------------------------
 _______PAGES.YML______   __________USERS.YML__________
| one:                 | | one:                        |
|   url: one.html      | |    email: testmail@mail.com |
|                      | |                             |
| two:                 | | two:                        |
|   url: pageTwo.html  | |   email: two@mail.com       |
|______________________| |_____________________________|
```

When debugging, right before save a page the value is correct:

```
<Page id: nil, url: "a", user_id: 980190963, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

But after the test compleats my db is like:

```
--USERS

id        |email             |created_at          |updated_at          |
----------|------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
980190962 |testmail@mail.com |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |
298486374 |two@mail.com      |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |


--PAGES

id        |url          |contato_id |created_at          |updated_at          |
----------|-------------|-----------|--------------------|--------------------|
980190962 |one.html     |           |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |
298486374 |pageTwo.html |           |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |2017-03-21 17:43:50 |
```

Why my values for email and url are not being saved? Nor the fk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks not rspec, but I try to answer.

Rails can clean database table when you run the test, so it clean all your data in database and create new fixtures data saved in database.

Comment: Thank you. Is hard to realise that Rails clear all test data by default. The docs do not mention that in a clear way.